# Flutter firebase: get data from subcollection

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In my app, person A makes a post in a collection called "ADS". Person B clicks on the post and clicks on the button to send a request to person A. This creates a subcollection called "REQUESTS".

I want that in the case where person B clicks on the same post again and and if a request has already been sent to that particular post, a Text should appear that a request has already been sent.

Any help please?

```
final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
    
StreamBuilder(
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("ADS")
      .doc(widget.selectedAds?['Uid'] ?? "")//the doc id here is the id of the user who made the post. User B selects that post and makes the request
      .collection("REQUESTS")
      .snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done && snapshot.hasData) {
      return ListView.builder(
          // shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final passengerId =
                snapshot.data!.docs[index].get("UID"); //This is the id of the currentUser who sent the request
            passengerId == uid
                ? Text(
                    "Request already sent",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  )
                : Text(
                    "Send a request",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  );
            return null;
          });
    } else {
      return Text(
        "Send request",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      );
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure about this answer so you may need to make some additional changes btw.

use the else if statement :

```
else if (snapshot.hasData && 
snapshot.data!.docs.isNotEmpty) {
      return Text(
        "Request already sent")
```

I made some changes with respect to your code and it might come out like this. Make some changes if required.

```
final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;

StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("ADS")
      .doc(widget.selectedAds?['Uid'] ?? "")
      .collection("REQUESTS")
      .where("UID", isEqualTo: uid) // Filters requests for current user
      .snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return CircularProgressIndicator(); // Loading indicator will be visible (may be user friendly)
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text("Error loading requests");//Add whatever you want
    } else if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data!.docs.isNotEmpty) {
      return Text(
        "Request already sent",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      );
    } else {
      return ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          // Whatever you want to do
        },
        child: Text("Send a request"),//or whatever the text you want
      );
    }
  },
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't seem to work. It always shows the elevated button even after sending the request. Any other suggestion?